# remove addtocart button within custom module

Tags: php, events, magento

I'm building a custom module that in a specific case scenario needs to remove the "add to cart" button from a product view for preventing it to be added in cart.

I would not want to override the entire view block for this, so I tried to catch the `catalog_product_is_salable_after` event and from my observer when that specific condition is accomplished, make the product not `salable with ->setIsSalable(false);` .

The problem is that although this works and addtocart button is removed, in the listing part, this products appear as "`out of stock`".

Would anyone have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding `catalog_product_is_salable_after`, then you should edit template files too(I think).

try Changing "out of stock" to something else if your condition is met.

By the way i got a similar problem like yours [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73426/).

Comment: thank you for the response, however i managed to fix the issue by catching the"controller_action_predispatch" event , checking in my observer if the action name is 'checkout_cart_add' and empty the product params if necesary